# How to create a dynamic text template in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextfield

I would like to create a dynamic text template for user to type in in iOS.

Here is some example image:

[image]

[image]

I had tried to do it this way which i don't know is the correct way of doing it.

```
  var borderWidth: CGFloat = 5.0

  var view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 60, width: 250, height: 100))
  view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
  view.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
  labelTemplate.addSubview(view)


  var mask = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 60, width: 260, height: view.frame.size.height-50))

  mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
  view.layer.mask = mask.layer
```

How should i create something that allows user to input their string into a text template ? Should i create by adding a UIImageView behind the UILabel/UITextField ?

Answer (score 0):

If your template has static positions for text then just place `UITextField`s where they should be and let the user enter the text there, limiting the maximum number of characters if needed. 
If your templates contain graphic elements, then yes, add a `UIImageView` behind the input fields.
As for your code, refrain from setting element dimensions and positions using frames, [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
var backView: UIView!
var labelView: UILabel!

var maskPath: UIBezierPath!
var maskLayer: CAShapeLayer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(backView)
    //do the constraints
    backView.backgroundColor = .red


    labelView = UILabel()
    self.view.addSubview(labelView)
    //do the constraints
    labelView.text = "Seven sticks of dynamite"
    labelView.font = UIFont.init(name: labelView.font.fontName, size: 34)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


    maskPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: labelView.frame) // OR maskPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: CGRect.init(x: labelView.frame.minX - 20, y: labelView.frame.minY - 20, width: labelView.bounds.width + 40, height: labelView.bounds.height + 40))
    maskLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    backView.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

The backView can be a single color or image according to your need in the application, the mask can be made around the labelView which you add to the controller.